# Inject Object using dagger 2 like DbManager in Worker, to do db operation inside doWork() method, #WorkerManager

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, dagger, android-workmanager

Hi I am trying out new WorkerManager in my project and I am not able to figure out how to inject my DbManager class inside my TaskWorker to make use of dbmanager inside doWork() method of workermanager. Also not able to figure out due to TaskWorker Object creation in some what hidden.

code example

```
 mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(IMAGE_MANIPULATION_WORK_NAME,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.APPEND,
                OneTimeWorkRequest.from(TaskWorker.class));
```

>

```
public class TaskWorker extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "TaskWorker";

    @Inject   
    DbManager dbManager;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WorkerResult doWork() {return null;}
}
}
```

Comment: There's an issue adressing this: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1183

Comment: thanks, for sharing @DavidMedenjak, I have subscribed to that issue

Answer (score 0):

To inject fields in worker class
firstly you need to inject your worker class inside AppComponent :

```
 fun inject(worker: TaskWorker)
```

then inside worker's doWork() , you need to call inject:

```
 if(applicationContext is MyApp){
        var daggerAppComponent= DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(applicationContext as MyApp).build()
        daggerAppComponent.inject(this)
    }
```